# how to do docker-compose pip install with a proxy?

Tags: proxy, docker, pip, dockerfile, docker-compose

I am trying to get a docker-compose build to work. My original Dockerfile was,

```
FROM python:3.4.2-onbuild
```

And I have requirements.txt as,

```
Django==1.8.1
gunicorn==19.3.0
psycopg2==2.6
redis==2.10.3
```

Because it's behind a proxy, pip install can't reach outside without --proxy,

```
Downloading/unpacking Django==1.8.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement Django==1.8.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
```

I tried to change the Docker file to this and it's not taking the --proxy pip option,

```
FROM python:3.4.2-onbuild

ENV HTTP_PROXY="http://<PROXY>"
ENV PIP_OPTIONS="--proxy $HTTP_PROXY"

ADD requirements.txt /requirements.txt

RUN pip install --proxy $HTTP_PROXY --requirement /requirements.txt
```

But, docker-compose doesn't seem to take the Dockerfile even when I do --no-cache.

Answer (score 2):

Does your change work when doing a `docker build` manually (not inside composer)?

Once you know you have it working with a normal docker build, you should be able to force docker-compose to rebuild using `docker-compose build`.

Comment: Thanks much! I think I found one thing that can get my Dockerfile going and it's to change FROM and not use "-onbuild", I believe with onbuild it's going to ignore local Dockerfile. I am yet to get my pip install with proxy to work, but, at least I am seeing my Dockerfile being exercised.

Comment: Got it! Both docker build and docker-compose build are working now. I guess I learnt the difference between regular and onbuild images?